# Issue with transformed/positioned DOM element in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, position, transform

I have an issue with links withing transformed/positioned DOM elements when using Chrome.

The HTML is composed of an `<ul>` with five `<li>` that are transformed/positioned to show a circular navigation menu (extracted from [the great work of Sara SOUEIDAN](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms)).

The list renders nicely as expected. However, in Chrome, the links under the `<li>` doesn't work as expected: when I click any link, nothing happen except for the last one (the 'e' link). In FireFox, the behavior is as expected.

Any idea what is the issue ?

The whole code can be found in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/younes_ouadi/re1Lonrz/).

Comment: interesting, because the same error seems to be there on the page that you're referring to...

Answer (score 1):

Remove

`position: fixed;`

From

`.cn-wrapper li a {`

Not sure what the displacement bug is where the comment is...but I'm gonna guess this is lesser of two issues.

Comment: By removing the `position: fixed;` from `.cn-wrapper li a`, the problem of the link is solved but a problem with the `tab` is created, again in Chrome only: try to press the `tab` key. Strange things will happen: the first item will disappear, the label of other items will disappear too...